# Background size in percent works like cropped contain in iOS

Tags: css, ios, background-image

This is my code:

```
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: right bottom;
background-image: url(https://someserver.com/image.png);
background-size: 45%;
```

The image is reduced in proportion to the width of the screen. However, on some iPhone models (like iPhone XR), the picture on the left side is cropped:

[image]

By increasing the `background-size`, I understood how it happens... first the device makes `background-size: 100%` and part of the image falls out of the viewport:

[image]

and then this cropped image is reduced to my `background-size: 45%`.

The first solution that comes up is to load a smaller image into the media query for the mobile device. But is it possible to solve this problem without doing that?